# Substitute new CRS for one specified in the Training Manual, Module 6, Lesson 6.2.5?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-3

This question came up on the page at the link https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/training_manual/vector_analysis/basic_analysis.html.

6.2.5 Try Yourself: Convert Layers’ CRS
Item 6. Change the [CRS] to WGS 84 / UTM zone 34S

In the Save Vector Layer as … dialog box, the fourth text box down shows

```
 CRS    EPSG:32734 - WGS 84 / UTM zone 34S
```

This doesn’t match any of the three choices in the dropdown menu. The second choice is

```
 EPSG:32700 - WGS 84 / UTM (southern hemisphere)
```

This CRS also appears in the list of Predefined Coordinate Reference Systems displayed in another dialog box obtained by clicking on the little ?globe icon to the right of the CRS menu. EPSG:32734 - WGS 84 / UTM zone 34S does not appear in the list.

Why does the instruction not match the choices? Will the choice of EPSG:32700 lead to error, or is this just a simplification of the reference labels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CRS drop down in the Save Layer dialog just gives you a selection of recently used CRS's. After you have opened the Coordinate Reference System Selector with the Select CRS button ('globe icon') shown below...

[image]

...you will have access to all the predefined Coordinate Reference Systems via a tree view which you can expand and browse:

[image]

To quickly find a particular CRS, you can use the filter function by entering part of the name or the EPSG code:

[image]

Comment: The filter was the key bit. I doubt I would have found it without the filter.